# ActorSystem.scheduler stops working after number of events

Tags: scala, akka, scheduler

I have a following scala snipet:

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem()
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
implicit val wsClient = AhcWSClient()
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global    

ActorSystem().scheduler.schedule(30.seconds, 5.minutes)(
{
  Logger.debug("5m tick")
  /* more code */
}
```

It's a part of home-automation application and it needs to be run long-term for months between restarts.

Right now, it ticks every 5 minutes, and produces a logging message to the console and file. There's also very simple method running below the Logger call, but it's not getting any errors.

The problem is, after ~2-3 days, the ticking stops. I've re-run the application several times and it seems to stop without any error, after this period of time. Couldn't find any help online, so I'm hoping some of you might ran at the same problem before and knows the answer.

Thanks,

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really tell what the issue is you have, but to make this more transparent for debugging you could use another approach.

Use an actor instead which uses `scheduleOnce` to schedule a message to himself instead of using the normal `schedule`:

```
def receive: Unit = {
    case "tick" =>
        Logger.debug("5m tick")
        context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(5.minutes, self, "tick")
}
```

In the parent of this actor you can use the `Restart` supervision directive, so in case the actor stops, it is just getting restarted.

Another option would be to look into the [Quartz-Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) which is a bit more extensive for long running tasks (and specifically written for this in contrast to Akka)

Comment: Thanks @thwiegan, I've tried the supervisor and Restart approach. Restarting works like a charm.

Comment: I wanted to know what's wrong with scheduler from akka, so I've wrapped around whole code with try-catch and found out that it seems that 3rd party api I'm calling is failing once in a few days. The method itself doesn't re-schedule another call when previous failed. Your solution, however, saves the situation.

Great, thanks again for your help.

Comment: Good solution! You could also do `schedule(0.minutes, 5.minutes, self, "tick")` in that actor, that should also keep sending `tick` messages even when the actor is restarted due to an exception.